# Search through RecyclerView- XamarinDroid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

I am able to search through my recyclerView but then what happens is, the search item when clicked is being affected by the layout postion. For instance i have

- Mac Book Pro
- Nintendo
- Nintendo plus

When i search Nintendo, Nintendo comes only appears in the 1st position. When i click on Nintendo, it gives me the details of Mac Book Pro instead. and when i search for something like `Nint`, it will display Nintendo and Nintendo plus which is cool. But then, since Nintendo plus is apparently in the 2nd position now, when i click on it, it gives me the details of Nintendo. Why is the search not affecting the layout position please?

**Activity**

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {

            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.top_menus, menu);

            var item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.search);

            var searchview = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView)MenuItemCompat.GetActionView(item);

            searchview.QueryTextChange += (s, e) => adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter(e.NewText);


            searchview.QueryTextSubmit += (s, e) =>

            {
                adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Searched for: " + e.Query, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                e.Handled = true;

            };

            MenuItemCompat.SetOnActionExpandListener(item, new SearchViewExpandListener(adapter));



            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        }

        private class SearchViewExpandListener : Java.Lang.Object, MenuItemCompat.IOnActionExpandListener
        {
            private readonly IFilterable _adapter;

            public SearchViewExpandListener(IFilterable adapter)
            {
                _adapter = adapter;
            }

            public bool OnMenuItemActionCollapse(IMenuItem item)
            {
                _adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter("");
                                return true;
            }

            public bool OnMenuItemActionExpand(IMenuItem item)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

**Adapter**

```
public class GameFilter : Filter
        {
            public readonly GameAdapter _adapter;
            public GameFilter(GameAdapter adapter)
            {
                _adapter = adapter;
            }

            protected override FilterResults PerformFiltering(ICharSequence constraint)
            {
                var returnObj = new FilterResults();
                var results = new List<Games>();
                if (_adapter._originalData == null)
                    _adapter._originalData = _adapter.games;

                if (constraint == null) return returnObj;

                if (_adapter._originalData != null && _adapter._originalData.Any())
                {

                    results.AddRange(
                        _adapter._originalData.Where(
                            games => games.Name.ToLower().Contains(constraint.ToString())));
                }

                returnObj.Values = FromArray(results.Select(r => r.ToJavaObject()).ToArray());
                returnObj.Count = results.Count;

                constraint.Dispose();

                return returnObj;


            }

            protected override void PublishResults(ICharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
            {
                    using (var values = results.Values)
                    _adapter.games = values.ToArray<Java.Lang.Object>()
                        .Select(r => r.ToNetObject <Games>()).ToList();

                _adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

                constraint.Dispose();
                results.Dispose();           
            }
        }
```

**activity**

```
           adapter = new Adapter(person,this);
            rv.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            rv.SetItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            rv.SetAdapter(adapter);

            adapter.ItemClick -= OnItemClick;
            adapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;
            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

 void OnItemClick(object sender, int position)
        {



                Intent Detail = new Intent(this, typeof(DetailActivity));

                Detail.PutExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_ID, person[position].Uid);


                StartActivity(Detail);

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Detail.PutExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_ID, person[position].Uid);
```

Where you're getting the person[position] you're using the position of the item in the filtered list to grab an item from the unfiltered list.

You need to use the filtered index (position) with the filtered items to access the correct object. Try accessing the item list through the adapter to get the correct item like so:

```
var item = adapter.GetItem(position);
Detail.PutExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_ID, item.Uid);
```

Comment: How do i use the filtered index please? Because i have your highlighted line  in my code

Comment: How does your answer relate to what you just said?

Comment: Ensure clarity in your answer before posting please

Comment: How are you mapping  Uid to item?

Comment: I don't understand your answer